# SML: Why no new line can't be written to file with "\n"

Tags: io, sml

Below is a simple program to write an int list to a file:

```
fun write(num_list, file) = 
let 
    val output = TextIO.openOut file
    fun num(nil) = TextIO.closeOut output
      | num(n::ns) = (TextIO.output(output, Int.toString(n)); TextIO.output(output, "\n"); num(ns))
in
    num(num_list)
end;
```

Why no new line was written to file after each number printed?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your code works and that a newline character is written after each number.

I have provided an alternative definition for your `write` function, but both appear to work.

```
fun writeInts (ints, filename) = 
    let val fd = TextIO.openOut filename
        val _ = List.app (fn i => TextIO.output (fd, Int.toString i ^ "\n")) ints
        val _ = TextIO.closeOut fd
    in () end

fun read filename =
    let val fd = TextIO.openIn filename
        val content = TextIO.inputAll fd
        val _ = TextIO.closeIn fd
    in content end

val test = (writeInts ([1,2,3,4], "hello.txt"); read "hello.txt" = "1\n2\n3\n4\n")
```

Comment: Ok...then maybe it's because of my system?? Do you have any idea why this may not work on some system?

Comment: Yes, perhaps your system uses a different line termination sequence. On Windows this would be `"\r\n"`.

Comment: @SimonShine, text streams SML do newline conversion as one would expect, so no need to write "\r\n" on Windows (in fact, it would be wrong to do that).

Comment: @Silvia.H, what system are you on, and how did you verify that no newline was written?

Comment: Windows 10. I run the program and the numbers are printed without any blank spaces or new lines in between.

Comment: @Silvia.H: I provided a test that should return true, even on your system. Your answer as to how you verified that no newlines were written is insufficient. If you open the file in Notepad, for example, it is not unlikely that it might discard the `\n`s. You can try this code on a Unix by going to [try.mosml.org](http://try.mosml.org/).

Comment: I open the file exactly in Notepad and there is no new line. Well actually I am a bit confused with my system as well. Like several days ago I install and configure the gcc complier but cmd can not find it at all, although environmental variable has been added to path. Other weird things like language packages mixed up and missing happen also...But sorry this is already irrelevant to the question. Thank you for your help :)