# SML: How to write two lists in files with ML

Tags: io, sml, ml

This function writes a list of reals to a file:

```
fun writeReal (real, filename) = 
    let val fd = TextIO.openOut filename
        val _ = map ( fn i =>  TextIO.output (fd, Real.toString i ^ "\r\n")) real
        val _ = TextIO.closeOut fd
    in () end
```

Calling the function:

```
writeReal ([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0], "hello.txt")
```

writes the following to the file *hello.txt*:

```
1.0 
2.0 
3.0 
4.0
```

If I had two lists, one containing a list of reals, and the other a list of words, how do I read and write the two lists to the file? For example:

```
writeReal ([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0], [one, two, three, four] , "hello.txt")
```

should write the following to the file *hello.txt*:

```
1.0 one
2.0 two
3.0 three
4.0 four
```

Answer (score 1):

First, here is some general feedback:

1. It is good custom to [attribute your sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33618409/235908), which in this case would provide some context.
2. A function that writes many reals to a file should perhaps be called `writeReals` (plural).
3. Since you discard the results of `List.map`, consider using [`List.app`](https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/master/src/mosmllib/List.sml#L62).

> If I had two lists, one containing a list of reals, and the other a list of words, how do I read and write the two lists to the file?

- I would recommend that you actually write a list of pairs, rather than a pair of lists. A list of pairs, e.g. `[(1.0, "Hello"), (2.0, "World")]`, will always have an equal number of reals and strings. A pair of lists, e.g. `([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], ["Hello", "World"])` will not necessarily have that.

  If you are forced to work with a pair of lists, you can convert them into a list of pairs using the built-in library function `ListPair.zip` like so:

  ```
  - ListPair.zip ([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], ["Hello", "World"]);
  > val it = [(1.0, "Hello"), (2.0, "World")] : (real * string) list
  ```
- **Writing a list of pairs,** here are some hints:

  1. Write a function, `pairToString : (real * string) -> string` that converts a single pair into a line that can be written to file. For example, `pairToString (1.0, "Hello")` should produce the string `"1.0 Hello\r\n"`.
  2. Apply this function using your framework function above:

     ```
     fun writeRealStringPairs (pairs, filename) =
         let val fd = TextIO.openOut filename
             val _ = List.app ... pairs
             val _ = TextIO.closeOut fd
         in () end
     ```

     where you replace `...` with something sensible.
- **Reading a list of pairs,** here are some hints:

  1. Write a function `pairFromString : string -> (real * string)` that converts a line from file into a pair. For example, `pairFromString "1.0 Hello\r\n"` should produce the pair `(1.0, "Hello")`.

     This function is what's called a *parser* and is not completely trivial to write. You might have luck playing around with the function [`String.tokens`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/string.html#SIG:STRING.tokens:VAL) in combination with e.g. [`Char.isSpace`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/char.html#SIG:CHAR.isSpace:VAL) and [`Real.fromString`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/real.html#SIG:REAL.scan:VAL). Notice that `Real.fromString` actually returns a value of type *real option* in case it fails, so you need to pattern match using e.g.

     ```
     case Real.fromString word1 of
          NONE   => raise Fail ("Couldn't parse as number: " ^ word1)
        | SOME r => r
     ```
  2. Apply this function to each line in a file, e.g. by doing:

     ```
     fun isLinebreak c = c = #"\r" orelse c = #"\n"
     fun readRealStringPairs filename =
         let val fd = TextIO.openIn filename
             val content = TextIO.inputAll fd
             val _ = TextIO.closeIn fd
             val lines = String.tokens isLinebreak content
             val pairs = List.map ... lines
         in pairs end
     ```

     where you replace `...` with something sensible.